# Did the Porsche which Paul Walker was in at the time of death have a different number plate to the one he was last seen in alive?

Tags: celebrities

I came across a site where [in the comments section somebody says that the number plate of the Porsche he was last seen in, was different from the one that crashed](http://hollywoodlife.com/2013/12/06/is-paul-walker-alive-not-dead-twitter-still-living/). I've tried challenging this claim, but interestingly enough, I managed to find a picture of the last moment of Walker's life where the number plate of the Porsche he got in is shown, but I've searched up dozens of the car crash photos and not one shows even a hint of the number plate. Maybe I'm not looking closely, but can anyone shed light on this topic?

Answer (score 11):

No, it's not true. The claim is based on pictures of the license plate at the crash site memorial, which is not actually the plate that was on the car at the time of the crash.

Here is the last picture of Paul Walker, with the car:

[image: Paul alive with his car]
<sup>Can be seen on [TMZ](http://www.tmz.com/2013/11/30/paul-walker-final-photo-before-deadly-crash-porsche/), [Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/gossip/paul-walker-dies-crash-report-article-1.1533786) and others.</sup>

Note the holder around the license plate has the words "Always Evolving".

Here is the picture of the license plate with a different number at the scene:

[image: License plate at Walker memorial]

<sup>The pictures of the "fake" license plate can be seen at various sites that either discuss the accident or the conspiracy theory.</sup>

It's clearly seen that it's outside the crash zone, as marked by the police line. And obviously part of a memorial. Also note that now there is a license plate holder that says "Fast Way racer". Another indication that this didn't come from the car in the first picture. Again, something someone else placed there as part of the memorial.

Now look at the car after the crash:

[image: Walker's car after the accident]

The car is destroyed beyond recognition, yet the license plate in question looks almost new, no dents, no sign of the fire that burned the car, even the plastics and the lettering on it are intact. It's highly improbable that the license plate was part of the car, wasn't burned or damaged during the accident and then was left at the scene by the police/authorities.

Comment: look at the top part of the license plate the screw holes are enlarged indicative of the screw head being pulled through, and it is bent a bit (and it looks a back plate not a front plate)

Comment: @ratchetfreak, the back of the car is burned to crisp. The whole interior is burned even the back tires are partially melted. The whole car is ruined beyond recognition, yet all the plate has is a small dent. It isn't really consistent. You can still clearly see the lettering on the plastic casing of the plate.

Comment: or it was thrown clear prior to the explosion,... either way we are just doing some speculation

Comment: @Transmissionfrom, I pointed to the lettering to show it's not damaged. I doubt that the plastic casing, the color of the plate and the lettering on the plastic would all survive a crash and a fire. Regarding "thrown clear" there would need to be a force separating the plate from the car before the accident. Throwing it back, away from the car so it would not be burned. There isn't such force in a car collision, things are thrown forward by inertia, not back.

Comment: The physics part was about the plate separating the car before the accident, and was in response to @ratchetfreak.

Comment: Please provide sources for these images.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - that's not a rear plate, it's a front plate. In California there would be year and month stickers in the two upper corners of the plate (like the ones visible on the plates shown on the Porsche.

Comment: Note that in the fake photo you can see a destroyed steering wheel on the left. In the pictures of the crash the steering wheel is one of the few recognizable objects remaining the car.

Comment: @ChrisR, it's not a fake photo, it's a real photo of the memorial fans erected at the crash site.